# R Shiny: Use filtered datatable and filter again

Tags: r, filter, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I am new to Rshiny and I hope you can help me with something:

I want to have different sidebar-tabs that kind of guide through data manipulation of one dataframe. So on the first one there will be some filtering (rows) and on the next tab the resulting dataframe will be processed further.

Here is some simplified code as an example:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Test"),
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Filter1", tabName = "filter1"),
      menuItem("Filter2", tabName="filter2")
    )
  ),
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName="filter1",
              DT::DTOutput("tbl1")),
      tabItem(tabName="filter2",
              DT::DTOutput("tbl2"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- data.frame(
    sample(c("A","B","C"),10,replace=TRUE),
    sample(c(1,2),10,replace=TRUE),
    sample(c(3,5,7,8),10,replace=TRUE)
  )
  colnames(data) <- c("var1","var2","var3")

  output$tbl1 <- DT::renderDT(
    data,
    filter="top")

  output$tbl2 <- DT::renderDT(
    data[input$tbl1_rows_current,],
    filter="top")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you run the example you will see, that filtering of the columns that have been filtered previously, is disabled in the second tab.

I can't figure out how to store the filtered dataframe from the first tab as a "new" dataframe input, so it can be filtered once again in the second tab. I tried storing the filtered dataframe with a reactive({}) expression as follws:

`newdata <- reactive({as.data.frame(data[input$tbl1_rows_current,])})`

but that didn't work (I got the error "Error in datatable: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)", which is why I specified as.data.frame())

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I just ran your code above, and when the Filter 1 tab is selected, I can filter a column of the data frame. When I go to Filter 2 tab, I see the filtered data frame and I can perform a second level filter on a different column. When I go back to Filter 1 tab, the original dataframe is preserved. This seems to be the goal you describe above. Maybe you have an environment issue? I ran your code on R3.6.3 on Win10x64 and RStudio v1.2.5033

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I would like is to filter the same column again, let's say in tab1 I filter A and B in the first column and in tab2 I want to filter only A. Tab1 should stay the same though. So I want them to be independent dataframes and tab2 just gets the initial input from tab1.

Comment: When column filters are enabled, filters with only one unique value will be disabled by design.  So if on the Filter1 tab in the var1 column you select just A, the var1 filter will be disabled on the Filter2 tab because now there is only one unique value in that column.  If you selected A and B on the Filter1 tab, you would still be able to filter further to just A on the Filter2 tab.